# Should I use a Bootstrapper class in a WebApi project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Starting with ASP.Net 5, I wanted to lay the foundation to my project. As of now, I created 2 projects.

1. Project - The WebApi project that comes with a Startup class.
2. Project.Server - A dll project that will hold all the business logic.

At first I though I should write a Bootstrapper class in "Project.Server" that will allow me to hide many parts of that dll (that "Project" doesn't need to know about), but then I found myself thinking I may be doing some extra work; In "Project"'s Startup class I'm calling many of my Bootstrapper class.

Does this extra layer of abstraction needed in a WebApi project?
Although "Project.Server" is currently only referenced in "Project", but I still want to structure is correctly...

Comment: By Bootstrapper class do you mean Bootstrap ? the twitter-bootstrap ?

Comment: A class that provides a basic bootstrapping sequence and hooks ...

Comment: Have used something similar to make sure the UI project doesn't hold any references to the Infrastructure project when working on an Onion Architecture solution.

Because of the need to configure the IoC container within the startup class, the only solution was to move the configuration to a Bootstrapper project. 

It's just a little extra work but it makes it impossible for someone to "accidentally" retrieve data directly from within a controller or a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different people will have different opinions on how to structure your web app.  Personally, for me, it's a matter of how much work is involved.  If it's fairly easy for you to separate out your business logic into a separate DLL, then do it.  Even though there may not be any immediate advantages now (since Project is the only consumer of Project.Server), in the future, if you ever decide there needs to be another consumer of the business logic, it will be a lot easier to make that work.  However, if it's a lot of work to create this extra layer, then I'd say it's not worth it, since you can't really predict what the future might bring, and so why spend a ton of effort trying to code for a future that is unknown.